# USB Wifi slow on all ports except through hub?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

A ridiculous question about a ridiculous problem.

I have a USB wifi device and when i plug it in 2 of the USB slots in the back it is ridiculous slow. It goes <10k a second, usually 1k. When i put it in the other 2 slots it can get up to 200k. When i put it on my USB hub (which is connected in the front) i get my full speed. What gives? Is there something wrong with the usb device? How do i test it?

I did grab the latest driver from the manufacture website.

Comment: Where is the hub relative to sources of radio interference?  Where do you place this Wifi device when connected to the hub?  Try using a USB extension cable and place the Wifi device at the same spot as if using the hub.  Your Wifi device is a radio transmitter+receiver with an antenna.  Its location is crucial for proper operation/performance.

Comment: @sawdust I tried plugging it on all ports (several in the back, two in front). I'll try physically holding the extender by the ports i plug it into and see what happens. I doubt anything woukd

Comment: It sounds like 2 of the ports are not USB 2.0

Comment: @Ramhound incorrect. Related http://superuser.com/questions/411027/how-do-i-use-a-usb-wifi-device-properly

Answer (score 0):

Someone has connected a USB 1.1 case/card extender to one of the motherboard's USB 2.0 connectors. That's not a supported configuration. Cables and extenders cannot negotiate, and so they *must* support the highest mode supported by both ends of the things they connect. You cannot connect a USB 2.0 device to a USB 2.0 controller through a USB 1.1 cable or extender. (You can through a USB 1.1 hub, because a hub becomes the device at both ends.)

You should either not use the ports on the extender or replace the extender with a USB 2.0 extender such as [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=103&cp_id=10307&cs_id=1030701&p_id=2210&seq=1&format=4), [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00015Y0FK) or [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002IWEDSS).

Comment: Actually, its messed up so much you either misread or misunderstood. All the ports except the 2 i didnt test on are USB 2.0. The other 2 are USB3 ;). The extender is 2.0 as well but why it doesnt work directly connected baffles me.

Comment: The extender is the problem. It *appears* to be 2.0 because it's connected to a 2.0/3.0 port. But it doesn't actually support 2.0 speeds. It can't negotiate a lower speed because it's not a device, it's just wires/connectors.

Comment: No no no. I mean. IT WORKS on the extender. IT DOES NOT WORK ON THE TOWER. I'll repeat again. I can get expected speeds with the extender but NOT on the tower (which gives me 10k or 1k)

Comment: What does "on the tower" mean? Does it mean a USB port on your case that is connected to an extender that connects to the motherboard? If so -- that extender is the problem.

Comment: Using the wifi usb on ports built onto the tower/computer. This happens even on the port the extender is plugged into

Comment: Those ports connect to an extender which then plugs into the motherboard. If that extender is a USB 1.1 extender, then things will break horribly if you connect a USB 2.0/3.0 device to a USB 2.0/3.0 port through it. The ports you are having problems with most likely have USB 1.1 extenders. Replacing them with USB 2.0 extenders like the ones I linked to (or not using those ports) will solve the problem.

Comment: Ok thats fine if the extender is breaking it. But the extender makes it work properly.

Comment: You and I mean different things by "the extender". I mean whatever is between the USB connector in the case and the USB connector on the motherboard. That is where the problem is.

Comment: ohh ok. I thought you meant the hub which does extend the reach (and port amount). The USB on the front are connected via cable, the ones in the back are directly on the motherboard so those do -not- have extenders. What bothers me the most is it works when theres something between the port i want to plug into and the device. I think i'll just refund this and try a different brand. No other USBs (storage mostly. although mouse/keyboard havent glicthed) have given me any issues.

Comment: The extenders are the problem that link the ports to the motherboard. If you replace them with an extender that is designed for USB 2.0, the problem will go away. When you operate devices out of spec, it is not unusual for it to work sometimes and in some combinations and not in others. I would strongly urge you to fix what's actually broken, lest it bite you again by corrupting data or something like that.

Comment: hmm, when i use a HDD on those ports i get USB 2 speeds such as >30megabyte per sec transfers. I know definitely that USB 1.1 cant do that. Also windows warns about plugging HDD into 1.1 slots. Anyways +1

Comment: They are USB 2.0/3.0 slots. They are capable of USB 2 speeds. The problem is that the extender is not a USB 2.0/3.0 extender. Of course you don't get an error, the extender has no way to tell you that it cannot support those speeds, it's just a piece of wire.

Comment: There's no difference in cable specifications between USB 1.0/1.1 and USB 2.0 (aside from max length). USB 1.1 at *low* speed (not even USB 1.1 *full*, which is more likely) would also be quite a lot faster than his reported speeds. And those extenders are rare nowadays, typically new motherboards come with several USB connectors physically attached (soldered), in the same general area as an onboard ethernet port, onboard audio ports, onboard video port, etc.

Comment: @Bob USB 1.1 cables and USB 2.0 cables comply with totally different specifications. For example, for USB 1.1 cables, there is no attenuation requirement at 200MHz. USB 2.0 cables must have no more than 3.2dB attenuation at 200MHz. Also, USB 2.0 cables are checked for crosstalk and leakage at USB 2.0 speeds while USB 1.1 cables are not. That's why many USB 2.0 cables contain ferrites and almost no USB 1.1 cables do. If a USB 1.1 cable needed a ferrite to operate reliably at USB 2.0 speeds, it wouldn't have it because nobody would know.

Comment: @Bob and david related question i wrote http://superuser.com/questions/411027/how-do-i-use-a-usb-wifi-device-properly having the device farther from the PC helped which explains why the hub got full speeds

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

Power - is the hub bus powered or self powered?  If it's self powered it may be supplying more power to the wifi adapter than your pc does.

Antena - the USB cable between the pc and hub may be acting as an antenna. Try using just a USB extension cable instead of the hub.

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/411027/how-do-i-use-a-usb-wifi-device-properly